# Complex Attributes UML Diagrams

Tags: class, attributes, uml, diagram

Just had to look into "Complex Attributes", admittedly I'm not an expert when it comes to this area but I was just wondering if this was in fact a correct "Complex Attribute" however pathetic is may be deemed. (I'm just trying to grasp basic knowledge for now!). Just found out I can't post pictures so... Here goes.

Entity - Car.

Attribute - RegNum

Attribute - Year

Entity - Tyres

Attribute - NumberOfTyres

(COMPLEX ATTRIBUTE?) - TyreBrand[0..*]

Insinuating the tyres could have multiple brands?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right

Entity - Tyres
Attribute - NumberOfTyres 
(COMPLEX ATTRIBUTE?) - TypeBrand[0..*]

Express the fact that a "Types" object could have multiple "Typebrand".

Regards,

BR

Comment: Thank you very much! Mind at rest now. Have a good day and an even better life ahead of you, Sir!

Answer (score 0):

The UML spec makes no mention of "complex attribute"; however, the multiplicity expressed within square brackets in `TyreBrand[0..*]` is indeed the way to specify that a `Tyre` can have zero or more `TyreBrand` values.

Be careful with your terminology, though. When one uses the term "complex attribute", it usually describes whether an attribute's *type* has a simple or complex *structure*. For example, a phone number can be stored as a scalar `String` value (e.g., "+1 800-555-5555") or as a complex `Telephone Number` datatype with its own `country code`, `area code`, `exchange`, and `station` attributes of type `String` (e.g., "+1", "800", "555", "5555"). Just to be clear, a `Telephone Number` datatype would look like a class on a diagram, but with the «datatype» keyword at the top. It can be used as an attribute type instead of `String`.